# Spring : Transactions not rolling back

Tags: spring, jdbc, transactions, rollback

I am trying to transact my service layer with Spring 3.0 annotation based transactions. I am configuring the transaction support for spring as follows:

I am using `DataSourceTransactionManager` for my transactions.

```
<bean id="summaryDailyTXManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">  

  <property name="dataSource" ref="summaryDailyDataSource"/>

</bean>
```

And I configure the annotation based support as follows:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="summaryDailyTXManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

After this I use the following annotation for my transactable functions:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
public void doSomething() {
// my code
}
```

My understanding is this that if there is any exception from the `doSomething` function, the transaction will rollback. But it is not rolling back. Please guide me if I have done something wrong or am I missing something.

Thanks.

Regards
Gillani

Comment: Please show us the code which gets a reference to the object containing this method and which calls this method.

Comment: Has your data source autocommit disabled ?

Answer (score 4):

what's your database?
sometimes its a database problem.

MySQL for instance with MyISAM tables do not have transactions.
No matter how you configure spring or native JDBC without Spring or use JTA or Hibernate, you can never get a ROLLBACK.

If I faced a similar problem, I'd isolate the problem by ruling out Spring.

Create a native non-spring jdbc method.

get a connection

set auto commit false

insert one record

insert another record

rollback the connection

close the connection

inspect manually if the record has been inserted

Comment: this was exactly my problem.  drove me crazy trying to figure out why my transactions were not rolling back.  thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

because spring rolls back only when runtimeException is throwed out by default.